# Convergence a.s. from convergence in probability (Steele's book)

Tags: random-variables, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

In Steele's *Stochastic Calculus and Financial Applications*, on top of p. 114:
[image]

The highlighted portion is an argument for surmising almost sure convergence from convergence in probability by passing to a subsequence. I must be missing something, because I don't see how this argument wouldn't imply more generally, meaning that the two modes of convergence are equivalent (which they, of course, are not).

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking about if/why convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely over a subsequence, or if you are asking about applying that to this particular context and related contexts. In the latter case, the particular structure of how this is applied is missing from your question.

Comment: I understand that if the subsequence is sufficiently sparsified, Borel-Cantelli can be invoked to conclude a.s. convergence over that subsequence. I don't see how this can be applied to the whole sequence. In general, it obviously cannot be, but I don't see any particular structure specific to the stated setting being invoked.

Comment: You say "I don't see how this can be applied to the whole sequence" but I do not see that being applied to the whole sequence anywhere. Again, the particular application of this fact is missing from your question; perhaps the missing part is what you are interpreting as being applied to the whole sequence.

Comment: For any fixed $t$, it is shown earlier that $A_n, B_n, C_n$ all converge in probability; this part I follow. Then an argument is made that they converge a.s. -- this argument I don't follow. It does not seem to rely on any particular properties of these objects.

Comment: From the excerpt you give, I do not see any claims that they converge almost surely.  The excerpt states the fact that there is a **subsequence** over which they converge almost surely.

Comment: The answer below has cleared it all up. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was proved that $A_n, B_n$ and $C_n$  converges in probability to $I_1, I_2$ and $0$ correspondly.

Let us take $n_k$ such that $A_{n_k}$ converges to $I_1$ a.s. It's possible - see, e.g., math.stackexchange.com/questions/222264
As $B_{n_k}$ converges to $I_2$ in probability we may take $B_{n_{k_j}}$ from $B_{n_k}$ such that $B_{n_{k_j}} 
\to I_2$ a.s.  Finally we will take ${n_{k_{j_l}}} $ such that $C_{n_{k_{j_l}}} \to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Ah, I got it -- thanks! The point is that it's enough to prove a.s. convergence for *any* sequence increasing to infinity!

Comment: @Aryeh, you are welcome!